# Reading in both strings and ints from a text file c++

Tags: c++, iostream

ok, heres the deal.  Below I the input from my file.

```
 3332453:Ryan:77 Easy Street
 3324532:Tom:1 Victory Lane
 3326854:Gary:69 Sexual Ave
 3304357:Susan:11 Straight Road
 3343651:Frank:96 Backwards street
```

What i am trying to do is read in the number, then the name, followed by the address and store them into a `BST`. After checking through everything, I think my insert is working fine. It correctly inserts the Name and Address into each position, but key1 keeps being either 0 or -955472. The above numbers are all suppose to be 7 digits long (phone numbers).   Below is what I would consider my closest attempt I have so far. Im not asking for someone to just give me code (although it would help) but rather explain to me why my implementation is not working, as well as how I can improve it. Thank you.

```
 ifstream dataFile;
dataFile.open ("/Users/revaes12/Desktop/BinarySearch/BinarySearch/phone.dat.rtf");
for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
{
        getline(dataFile, tmp,  ':');
        person[counter].key1 = atoi(tmp.c_str());
        getline(dataFile, person[counter].name1,':');
        getline(dataFile, person[counter].address1);

        PNTree.insert(person[counter].key1, person[counter]);
}
dataFile.close();
```

The prototype for the `insert` call is "`template <class KeyType, class DataType> bool BST<KeyType, DataType>::insert (KeyType key, DataType data)`".
Also, I understand that atoi is C and not C++, but I also tried stringstream and that failed as well! Please help!

Comment: Is this the content of the file that you see when you open it in the Notepad, or is this really an RTF file?

Comment: First you should convert "phone.dat.rtf" to a plain text file.

Comment: why don't you use the >> operator?

Comment: @Kay not really required albeit rtf is a horrible format.

Comment: Is the first value a integer or a string of numeric digits?  Because 3 of those can't be converted to `int`s like you're trying to do.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Does it compile?  Does it run?  Does it crash?  Does it erase your hard drive?

Comment: Ok, I converted my file to a .txt file. When i use the debugger, I check the structs records, it inputs the name and address fine, but the numbers are either 0 or -955472 for each one, with what looks like no pattern

Comment: @user2167064: Are you absolutely certain that the phone numbers are 7 digits?  Because changing `int` to `long` shouldn't help if they're 7 digits.  However, that _would_ fix things if they are 9+ digits.  Are you certain they aren't 9 or 10 digits?  Also, I edited more information into the question, but can you get the right numbers in there?  They're pretty critical.  Finally, now that you solved the issue, please post that as an answer, and not as an edit.

Answer (score 2):

After attempting to [reverse-engineer your problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=66150f4871b1c16e6ade19731707780e-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba), I think that `PNTree.insert` is wrong.  Assuming that `PNTree` is a `std::map<int, person_type>`, then the `insert` method of that does not take two parameters of those types.  The three insert members are below.

```
pair<iterator,bool> insert (const value_type& val);
iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);
template <class InputIterator>
void insert (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

and `value_type` is a `std::pair<int, person_type>`. I presume you wanted the first one, to insert a *node*, in which case, the easiest thing would be:

```
PNTree[person[counter].key1] = person[counter];
```

Also note that several of those "numbers" cannot be converted to an `int`, they're simply to big.  You'll have to either use `long long`, or `std::string` to hold those.

If I were to write this code, it would look more like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c8d738ebfef1112aa33bf64179ac04fd-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba).

Comment: After checking through everything, I think my insert is working fine, It correctly inserts the Name and Address into each position, but adds whacky numbers into key1.  Also, the above numbers are wrong.. idk what happened when I posted the question, they are all suppose to be 7 digits long (phone numbers). As for what the insert function accepts, it looks as follows

Comment: template <class KeyType, class DataType>
bool  BST<KeyType, DataType>::insert (KeyType key, DataType data)

Comment: @user2167064: see, knowing that you wre using a `BST` class would have been _VERY_ helpful to know.